# How to removing spacing in SQL

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, datastage

I have data in DB2 then i want to insert that data to SQL.

The DB2 data that i had is like :

```
select char('AAA   ') as test from Table_1
```

But then, when i select in SQL after doing insert, the data become like this.

```
select test from Table_1
```

result :

```
test
------
AAA
```

why Space character read into box character. How do I fix this so that the space character is read into.

Or is there a setting I need to change? or do I have to use a parameter?

I used AS400 and datastage.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "insert that data to SQL"? Is your destination database in SQL Server?

Comment: You could do a simple update on SQL Server to replace box char with space. `UPDATE Table_1 SET test = REPLACE(test, '', ' ')`

Answer (score 1):

Datastage appends pad characters so you know that there are spaces there. The pad character is 0x00 (NUL) by default and that's what you're seeing.

Research the APT_STRING_PADCHAR environment variable; you can set it to something else if you want.

The 0x00 characters are not actually in your database. The short answer is, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: i try 0x00, but the pad character increasingly. and i try with 0x20 but i got the same result.

Comment: Another possibility is a column size mismatch. <http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21497316> I don't think this is your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

When you said:

```
select char('AAA   ') as test from Table_1
```

You were not actually showing any data from the table.  Instead you were showing an expression casting a constant `AAA` as a character value, and giving that result column the name `test` which coincidentally seems to be the name of a column in the table, although that coincidence doesn't matter here.

Then your 2nd statement does show the contents of the database column.

```
select test from Table_1
```

Find out what the hexadecimal value actually is.